# i need help about jquery.countdown.js by keith-wood

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

[Quick Reference jquery countdown js](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

i try to code

```
<div class="countdown-container" id="sales_timer_display_to'.$product->get_id().'" data-date-to="'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$sale_price_dates).'"></div>
```

and `data-date-to` console log `2020-04-26 03:10:00`

```
var datadate_to = $elem.attr("data-date-to");
        
        console.log(datadate_to);
        var year_to = datadate_to.split("-")[0];
        var month_to = datadate_to.split("-")[1];
        var days_to = datadate_to.split("-")[2];
        var hour_to = datadate_to.split(":")[3];
        var minue_to = datadate_to.split(":")[4];
        var second_to = datadate_to.split(":")[5];

        var dayz_to = new Date(year_to, month_to - 1, days_to, hour_to, minue_to, second_to);
        console.log(dayz_to);

            $elem.countdown({ 
            until: dayz_to,
```

this function don't work, console log `dayz_to` showing error, right answer should be like this `Sun Apr 26 2020 03:10:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)`
pls i need this work

Comment: *"console log dayz_to showing error"* - And that error is.... ?

Comment: error showing `Invalid Date` with console.log(dayz_to)

Comment: Then it's an invalid date.  What are the values you're using to build the date?  `year_to`, `month_to`, etc.  Output everything to the console so you have all of that information.  (Or, even better, use the browser's script debugger to step through the code as it executes and observe all of the variable values.)

Comment: This is a great time to start familiarizing yourself with your debugging tools.  To start, closely examine the runtime values you’re using for day, hour, minute, and second.  They’re not what you assume they are.  “26 03:10:00” is not a valid day, and the next three are all undefined.

Comment: yeah i try to delete `var hour_to` `var minue_to` `var second_to ` and `, hour_to, minue_to, second_to` then run code again and worked, problem about hour,minue,and second form
i try to code with Reference here http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
`until: null, // new Date(year, mth - 1, day, hr, min, sec) - date/time to count down to 
        // or numeric for seconds offset, or string for unit offset(s): 
        // 'Y' years, 'O' months, 'W' weeks, 'D' days, 'H' hours, 'M' minutes, 'S' seconds `
but still not work, pls help me fix this. i want add hout minue and second too

Comment: i fixed problem, thanks David